# Why does trying to use `datetime.strptime` result in " 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'"?

Tags: python, string, datetime, type-conversion, datetime-format

I'm using [strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert a date string into a `datetime`. According to the linked page, formatting like this should work:

```
>>> # Using datetime.strptime()
>>> dt = datetime.strptime("21/11/06 16:30", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
```

My code is:

```
import datetime
dtDate = datetime.strptime(sDate,"%m/%d/%Y")
```

where `sDate = "07/27/2012"`. (I understand, from the same page, that `%Y` is *"Year with century as a decimal number."*)

I have tried putting the actual value of sDate into the code:

```
dtDate = datetime.strptime("07/27/2012","%m/%d/%Y")
```

but this does not work. The error I get is:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error is probably that the function isn't in the module. Try import datetime from datetime. Or invoke as datetime.datetime.strptime

Comment: @MartijnPieters: thanks. As soon as I posted it, I realised I should have added that... :)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You should be using `datetime.datetime.strptime`.  Note that very old versions of Python (2.4 and older) don't have `datetime.datetime.strptime`; use [`time.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) in that case.

Answer (score 34):

You are importing the module datetime, which doesn't have a `strptime` function.

That module *does* have a `datetime` object with that method though:

```
import datetime
dtDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(sDate, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Alternatively you can import the `datetime` object from the module:

```
from datetime import datetime
dtDate = datetime.strptime(sDate, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Note that the `strptime` method was added in python 2.5; if you are using an older version use the following code instead:

```
import datetime, time
dtDate = datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(sDate, "%m/%d/%Y")[:6])
```

Answer (score 8):

Because `datetime` is the module. The class is `datetime.datetime`.

```
import datetime
dtDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(sDate,"%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: Thanks, but then I get: **AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'**

Comment: @Wikis: do you have another module named `datetime` in your project?

Comment: No. `datetime` is used in another place: `now = datetime.datetime.now()` if that's any help.

Comment: @Wikis: are you using a python version before 2.5, by any chance?

Comment: In relation to the same question I am trying to do something like this -     `dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("2016-01-12T03:16:10.815675+00:00", utc)` <br>                                                                                                  Ofcourse it is not working but just wondering is there a way to do it. I get a utc string and want to convert it to datetime object. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `strftime` static method from `datetime` class from `datetime` module. Try:

```
import datetime
dtDate = datetime.datetime.strptime("07/27/2012", "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following,to import datetime

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

dt.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score -2):

If in the folder with your project you created a file with the name "datetime.py"