# matplotlib string to dates

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I am trying to convert a list of dates as strings to an x axis in matplotlib and I can't seem to get it to come out right.

```
dates =  ['2014-05-06', '2014-05-07', '2014-05-08', '2014-05-09', '2014-05-10', '2014-05-11', '2014-05-12', '2014-05-13']

import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import dates

converted_dates = matplotlib.dates.datestr2num(dates)
x_axis = (converted_dates)

y_axis = range(0,8)
pyplot.plot( x_axis, y_axis, '-' )
pyplot.show()
```

This brings back 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 on the x axis on the chart, what am I missing. I would like this to display 2014-05-06 etc

Comment: This duplicates, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486121/how-to-plot-data-against-specific-dates-on-the-x-axis-using-matplotlib

Comment: maybe I am wrong but those are datetime objects and not strings. I am trying to convert strings to 2 date numbers

Comment: cgn has the answer, assuming that what you need is for the plot to compare and space the dates correctly? I'm confused by " I would like this to display 2014-05-06 etc" when that's what you have to start with.

Comment: @cphlewis Yes, but you can't plot against a list of strings, you _can_ plot against a list of dates.

Comment: So what does .datestr2num do then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this the goal? (Threw in rotation because it almost always comes up, with dates.)

```
datelist =  ['2014-05-06', '2014-05-07', '2014-05-08', '2014-05-09', '2014-05-10',    '2014-05-11', '2014-05-12', '2014-05-13']

import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import dates
import datetime

converted_dates = list(map(datetime.datetime.strptime, datelist, len(datelist)*['%Y-%m-%d']))
x_axis = converted_dates
formatter = dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')


y_axis = range(0,8)
pyplot.plot( x_axis, y_axis, '-' )
ax = pyplot.gcf().axes[0] 
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
pyplot.gcf().autofmt_xdate(rotation=25)
pyplot.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The idea of using `matplotlib.dates.datestr2num` is in principle correct. You would then need to tell matplotlib to actually interprete the resulting numbers as dates. One easy option is to use `plot_date` instead of `plot`.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates

dates =  ['2014-05-06', '2014-05-07', '2014-05-08', '2014-05-09', 
          '2014-05-10', '2014-05-11', '2014-05-12', '2014-05-13']

converted_dates = matplotlib.dates.datestr2num(dates)
x_axis = (converted_dates)

y_axis = range(0,8)
plt.plot_date( x_axis, y_axis, '-' )

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `strptime`. Documentation is here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

For example:

```
import datetime
sDate = '2014-05-06'
dtDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(sDate,"%m-%d-%Y")
```

matplotlib can compare datetime objects.

Comment: Also potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070193/why-is-datetime-strptime-not-working-in-this-simple-example

Comment: That is not really a duplicate, it uses `strptime`, but the issue in that case is calling the wrong module, not issues with making it work

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use numpy directly:

```py
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import dates
import numpy as np

dates =  ['2014-05-06', '2014-05-07', '2014-05-08', '2014-05-09',
          '2014-05-10', '2014-05-11', '2014-05-12', '2014-05-13']

converted_dates = np.array(dates, dtype='datetime64[ms]')

ydata = range(0,8)
pyplot.plot(converted_dates, ydata, '-' )
pyplot.show()
```