# Python Scripting with the date as an x-axis

Tags: python, date, plot, scripting

I'm getting a number of errors. Does anyone see something in the code that is sticking out like thorn?

```
from pylab import plot, show, title, xlabel, ylabel, legend
import matplotlib.dates as dates
title('AF16 compared to AF17')
xlabel('Month')
ylabel('Donation Amount')
legend([af16y, af17y])
af16x = dates.datestr2num[1/1/15,3/5/16]
af17x = dates.datestr2num[4/5/16, 2/2/17]
af16y = [3000,5000]
af17y = [350,7000]
plot(af16x,af16y,af17x,af17y)
```

mostly I know the legend and the dates are causing errors. This is a schmorgasborg of code so I knew I was running into errors. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: datestr2num is a function, which takes a list of string representations of dates.  Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644020/matplotlib-string-to-dates

Comment: I get an error pertaining to the legend:
    NameError: name 'af16y' is not defined

I just comment out the legend and then I get this error:
    af16x = dates.datestr2num[1/1/15,3/15/16]
    TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Comment: anyone looking for help with this concept go here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627686/plotting-dates-on-the-x-axis-with-pythons-matplotlib