# Converting Date to a number in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a date array

```
date_array = array(['September 11, 2012', 'September 5, 2012'])
```

I want to graph this date_array against a 
value, `value_array =array([25,28])`
using `matplotlib`

So I want to convert the date_array to a number like

```
date_as_number=array([20120812, 20120805])
```

so that I could plot the `date_as_number` as any other number against the `value_array`.

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644020/matplotlib-string-to-dates ? Please make it clear in how far other questions here do not solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Parse Dates

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

date_array = np.array(['September 11, 2012', 'September 5, 2012'])
[parse(x).date() for x in date_array]
```

Output:

[datetime.date(2012, 9, 11), datetime.date(2012, 9, 5)]

Comment: Excellent. That really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Set the date column as index and use the pandas builtin plot to get the date wise plot that you need. Below is an example

```
import random
import pandas as pd
data = [('September {}, 2012'.format(i),random.random()) for i in range(1,30)]
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['_date','value'])
data_df['_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df._date)
data_df= data_df.set_index('_date')
data_df.head()
```

This gives a dataframe like this

```
            value
_date   
2012-09-01  0.379791
2012-09-02  0.146355
2012-09-03  0.545267
2012-09-04  0.398388
2012-09-05  0.926643
```

Just plot this df.

```
 data_df.plot()
```

[image]