# over lapping on x-axis for second set of data python- order not preserved

Tags: matlab, matplotlib

I have two data sets and trying to show to data sets on the same graph for comparison. when plotting bar graphs on the same fig. I am seeing that 2 values are overshooting the x-axis. when I try individually, each graph looks good.2019-5-20,2019-5-28 data from second set comes at the end, not in the order.

My first data set looks like:

```
drray1 ['2019-05-21', '2019-05-22', '2019-05-23', '2019-05-24', '2019-05-27', '2019-05-29', '2019-05-31', '2019-06-01', '2019-06-03', '2019-06-04', '2019-06-07', '2019-06-10', '2019-06-11', '2019-06-12', '2019-06-13', '2019-06-14']
countarray1 [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 2, 7, 3]
```

and my second data set looks like:

```
drray2 ['2019-05-20', '2019-05-23', '2019-05-24', '2019-05-28', '2019-06-11', '2019-06-12', '2019-06-14']
countarray2 [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1]
```

when I try to plot bar graphs:

```
p1=plt.bar(darray1,countarray1,color="blue",edgecolor='white', 
width=barWidth,label="First Load")

p1=plt.bar(darray2,countarray2,color="Green", width=barWidth,label="Second Load")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are plotting strings so the order of dates is not recognized. You need to convert the strings dates into `datetime` objects using the method as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644020/matplotlib-string-to-dates)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates
import datetime

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

darray1 = ['2019-05-21', '2019-05-22', '2019-05-23', '2019-05-24', '2019-05-27', '2019-05-29', 
          '2019-05-31', '2019-06-01', '2019-06-03', '2019-06-04', '2019-06-07', '2019-06-10', 
          '2019-06-11', '2019-06-12', '2019-06-13', '2019-06-14'] 
countarray1 = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 2, 7, 3]

darray2 = ['2019-05-20', '2019-05-23', '2019-05-24', '2019-05-28', '2019-06-11', '2019-06-12', '2019-06-14'] 
countarray2 = [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1]

converted_dates_1 = list(map(datetime.datetime.strptime, darray1, len(darray1)*['%Y-%m-%d']))
converted_dates_2 = list(map(datetime.datetime.strptime, darray2, len(darray2)*['%Y-%m-%d']))
formatter = dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')

plt.bar(converted_dates_1,countarray1,color="blue",edgecolor='white', width=0.5,label="First Load")
plt.bar(converted_dates_2,countarray2,color="Green", width=0.5,label="Second Load") 

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How to show all date values in x-axis.  in the solution you solved, the graph is not showing all values on x-axes. I tried multiple ways. thanks