# Convert date string to datetime date but get exception in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am trying to convert date string m/d/YYYY  to `datetime.date` object. I tried to the following code but get an exception. Is there an easier way?

I get a formatting error for date conversion from string to Datetime date

```
df_fx = pd.read_csv('data/USDCAD.FXCM_D.txt',delim_whitespace=True, names = ["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Vol"])
```

Format is #%d/%m/%y which needs to converted to DateTime.Date object type

```
strDate = str(df_fx.Date)  #%d/%m/%y https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html
r.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(strDate, '%m/%d/%y').date() #stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime
#note error solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070193/why-is-datetime-strptime-not-working-in-this-simple-example
```

Note the last line generates an exception of:

```
r.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(strDate, '%m/%d/%y').date() #stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '0       06/13/2006\n1       06/14/2006\n2 ...11/01/2016\nName: Date, dtype: object' does not match format '%m/%d/%y'
```

I will assume it is the format is wrong but what is the best one. I used %Y as well.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the python module *datetime*:

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
print(str(dt.day) + " of the " + str(dt.month) + " month of the year " + str(dt.year))
```

This will print it in the format of:

```
3 of the 11 month of the year 2016
```

Comment: Thanks Lachlan but I rephrased the question at the beginning for exactly what I am looking for.