# Convert datetime to UTC in different order

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format

Trying to convert this date format `Thu Apr 26 22:51:49 PDT 2018` to UTC `2018-04-26T22:51:49Z` I dont care about the day part and can be excluded.

```
type(results[0].create_date)
```

returns

```
<class 'str'>
```

So far I have tried this

```
print (datetime.strptime((results[0].create_date), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
```

but failing with this error

```
ValueError: time data 'Thu Apr 26 22:51:49 PDT 2018' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
```

Comment: You should be using datetime.datetime.strptime https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070193/why-is-datetime-strptime-not-working-in-this-simple-example?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work is because the `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ` string pattern does not match how the date is represented in the `results[0].create_date` variable. `datetime.strptime` attempts to match the given string to the format you specify to extract a datetime object. Amending the formatter may help here, but you may have difficulty with the `PDT` part.

I suggest using the dateutil.parser module. You can do the following:

```
import dateutil.parser

x = parser.parse(results[0].create_date)
print x 

>>> 2018-04-26 22:51:49
```

This returns a datetime object and you can format however you want to include the 'T' and 'Z' as you suggested in your question.

**NOTE:** I have done this based on your given input and desired output. You must be aware however that `Thu Apr 26 22:51:49 PDT 2018 in UTC` is not equal to `2018-04-26T22:51:49Z` as PDT is 7 hours behind UTC.